# Counting Elements in Sahi

Tags: sahi

The search of a particular query displays the it's results in the form of a elements contained inside a div. How can I count the number of search results(elements) inside that div after the search is complete. **Note** : Results are inside a "div" and not a table. Hence the traditional **Count** used for counting rows and columns in a table cannot be applied here !

Comment: can you please post the code you are trying to use? What is your approach? Take some minutes to read the help section of StackOverflow to make your question good for this community

Comment: Thank You DaFois . I solved the problem by passing the div as jQuery as a parameter in the _eval method and then calling the length method within it .

Answer (score -2):

Isnt the below mentioned api working?
[_count Api](https://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/fetch-apis.html#_count)

You can use the api as below:

```
var $textboxCount = _count("_elementType", _in(_div($identifier));
```